# How to pipe one readable stream into two writable streams at once in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, gzip, zlib, gzipstream, node.js-stream

The goal is to:

1. Create a file read stream.
2. Pipe it to gzip (`zlib.createGzip()`)
3. Then pipe the read stream of zlib output to:

   1) HTTP `response` object

   2) **and** writable file stream to save the gzipped output.

Now I can do down to 3.1:

```
var gzip = zlib.createGzip(),
    sourceFileStream = fs.createReadStream(sourceFilePath),
    targetFileStream = fs.createWriteStream(targetFilePath);

response.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');

sourceFileStream.pipe(gzip).pipe(response);
```

... which works fine, but I need to also **save the gzipped data to a file** so that I don't need to regzip every time and be able to directly stream the gzipped data as a response.

**So how do I pipe one readable stream into two writable streams at once in Node?**

Would `sourceFileStream.pipe(gzip).pipe(response).pipe(targetFileStream);` work in Node 0.8.x?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found that zlib returns a readable stream which can be later piped into multiple other streams. So I did the following to solve the above problem:

```
var sourceFileStream = fs.createReadStream(sourceFile);
// Even though we could chain like
// sourceFileStream.pipe(zlib.createGzip()).pipe(response);
// we need a stream with a gzipped data to pipe to two
// other streams.
var gzip = sourceFileStream.pipe(zlib.createGzip());

// This will pipe the gzipped data to response object
// and automatically close the response object.
gzip.pipe(response);

// Then I can pipe the gzipped data to a file.
gzip.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(targetFilePath));
```

Comment: Downvote. This is redundant, doesn't add any new information at all and actually manages to increase confusion.

Comment: You cannot pipe writeable streams to anything: https://github.com/nodejs/readable-stream/blob/master/lib/_stream_writable.js#L193 you need a douplex or a readable stream to do that.

Answer (score 57):

Pipe chaining/splitting doesn't work like you're trying to do here, sending the first to two different subsequent steps:

`sourceFileStream.pipe(gzip).pipe(response);`

However, you can pipe the same readable stream into two writeable streams, eg:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var source = fs.createReadStream('source.txt');
var dest1 = fs.createWriteStream('dest1.txt');
var dest2 = fs.createWriteStream('dest2.txt');

source.pipe(dest1);
source.pipe(dest2);
```

Comment: Pipes **are** chainable. Checkout the Zlib doc http://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html. You can see `raw.pipe(zlib.createGzip()).pipe(response);`

I know the solution you've given, but it doesn't solve my problem because in my case I don't have a specific read stream. The data is generated by zlib at runtime, and I need to pipe its data to two writable streams.

Comment: Pipes are chainable? No if you take into account that the last pipe() doesn't work over the first `raw` stream. It's not like in jQuery that you chain to work on the same object. The last `pipe(response)` just takes the input from `gzip` not from `raw`.

Comment: As of 2018, I'm able to chain pipe() calls and get the data I expect. This is especially useful in something like an AWS Lambda function - read from a bucket as a stream; pipe to zlib gunzip; pipe to writable stream, which saves it to another bucket / key.

Comment: This answer me helped understand that the stream ends when piping to fs.createWriteStream, so after that point it can't be chained any further.

Answer (score -1):

you can use "readable-stream-clone" package

```
const fs = require("fs");
const ReadableStreamClone = require("readable-stream-clone");

const readStream = fs.createReadStream('text.txt');

const readStream1 = new ReadableStreamClone(readStream);
const readStream2 = new ReadableStreamClone(readStream);

const writeStream1 = fs.createWriteStream('sample1.txt');
const writeStream2 = fs.createWriteStream('sample2.txt');

readStream1.pipe(writeStream1)
readStream2.pipe(writeStream2)
```