# Race condition between two NodeJS streams when parsing a large JSON file

Tags: node.js, json

I have to parse a large (100+ MB) JSON file with the following format:

```
{
 "metadata": {
   "account_id": 1234
   // etc.
 },
 "transactions": [
   {
     "transaction_id": 1234,
     "amount": 2
   },
   // etc. for (potentially) 1000's of lines
 ]
}
```

The output of this parsing is a JSON array with the `account_id` appended to each of the `transactions`:

```
[
 {
   "account_id": 1234,
   "transaction_id": 1234,
   "amount": 2
 },
 // etc.
]
```

I'm using the [stream-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json) library to avoid loading the whole file into memory at the same time. stream-json allows me to [pick](https://github.com/uhop/stream-json/wiki/Pick) individual properties, and then stream them one at a time, depending on if they're an [array](https://github.com/uhop/stream-json/wiki/StreamArray) or [object](https://github.com/uhop/stream-json/wiki/StreamObject)

I'm also trying to avoid parsing the JSON twice by piping the read of the JSON file to two separate streams, [which is possible in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14174228/1475814).

I'm using a [Transform](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform) stream for generating the output, setting a property on the Transform stream object that stores the `account_id`.

Pseudo code (with obvious race condition) below:

```js
const { parser } = require('stream-json');
const { pick } = require('stream-json/filters/Pick');
const { streamArray } = require('stream-json/streamers/StreamArray');
const { streamObject } = require('stream-json/streamers/StreamObject');
const Chain = require('stream-chain');
const { Transform } = require('stream');

let createOutputObject = new Transform({
 writableObjectMode:true,
 readableObjectMode:true,
 transform(chunk, enc, next) => {
  if (createOuptutObject.account_id !== null) {
     // generate the output object
  } else {
     // Somehow store the chunk until we get the account_id...
  } 
 } 
});
createOutputObject.account_id = null;

let jsonRead = fs.createReadStream('myJSON.json');
let metadataPipline = new Chain([
  jsonRead,
  parser(),
  pick({filter: 'metadata'}),
  streamObject(),
]);

metadataPipeline.on('data', data => {
 if (data.key === 'account_id') {
  createOutputObject.account_id = data.value;
 }
});

let generatorPipeline = new Chain([
 jsonRead, // Note same Readable stream as above
 parser(),
 pick({filter: 'tracks'}),
 streamArray(),
 createOutputObject,
 transformToJSONArray(),
 fs.createWriteStream('myOutput.json')
]);
```

To resolve this race condition (i.e. converting to JSON array before `account_id` is set), I've tried:

- Using `createOutputObject.cork()` to hold data up until `account_id` is set.

  - The data just passes through to `transformToJSONArray()`.
- Keeping the `chunk`s in an array in `createOutputObject` until `account_id` is set.

  - Can't figure out how to re-add the stored `chunk`s after `account_id` is set.
- Using `setImmediate()` and `process.nextTick()` to call `createOutputObject.transform` later on, hoping that `account_id` is set.

  - Overloaded stack so that nothing could get done.

I've considered using stream-json's `streamValues` function, which would allow me to do a `pick` of `metadata` and `transactions`. But the [documentation](https://github.com/uhop/stream-json/wiki/StreamValues) leads me to believe that *all* of `transactions` would be loaded into memory, which is what I'm trying to avoid:

> As every streamer, it *assumes that individual objects* can fit in memory, but the whole file, or any other source, should be streamed.

Is there something else that can resolve this race condition? Is there anyway I can avoid parsing this large JSON stream twice?

Comment: wild guess... on the input side, instead of piping the JSON.read() ... you may be able to explicitly divy it up by reading to a buffer, do arrayCopy on the buffer , converting each of 2 buffers to separate instances of "readables" then, on 2 separate inputStreams from the 2 readables.   ie the arrayCopy provides encapsulation of the forked memory/objects.

Comment: Correct me if that's not your case - you want `stream1` to run until `account_id` is found, but not write to `stream2` until you have it. I could suggest using [rereadable-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rereadable-stream) I wrote and rewind the stream as soon as you found your account id.